# How do I get Facebook's custom login to display on my Main.storyboard and not just in my code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

I have successfully implemented my custom FB log in into my code and it displays/works when I run my simulator, however, I want to implement my custom design into it. Is there any way I can move it from my code and display it as a button on Storyboard to add said custom design.

Here is the code I've written already

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKLoginKit

class chooseLogInOrSignUpViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //add our custom FB log in here

    let customFBButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    customFBButton.backgroundColor = .blue
    customFBButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y:50, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
    customFBButton.setTitle("Connect with Facebook", for: .normal)
    customFBButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    view.addSubview(customFBButton)

    customFBButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomFBLogin), for: .touchUpInside)

}

func handleCustomFBLogin() {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self)
    { (result,err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Connect with Facebook failed", err)
            return

        }

        print(result?.token.tokenString)
}
```

}

```
  let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "usersVC")
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. You cannot view custom views in the storyboard. The storyboard only renders out certain UIkit views implemented by Apple.

You could use a custom view to help with positioning your facebook login and make it a subclass of the facebook login. But you would see nothing

Answer (score 0):

IBDesignable/IBInspectable

these help in making custom controls and allows to live preview the design right in the Interface builder.

Might help :

http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

http://www.appcoda.com/ibdesignable-ibinspectable-tutorial/

Comment: That doesn't allow him to view facebook login button. It just allows him to design his own views